# parallelization of session.run (tensorflow) using python multiprocess - for Inference

Tags: tensorflow, multiprocessing

folks, we are trying to deploy an OCR model on T2.xlarge ec2 instance ( 4 cores, 16 gigs ). The problem is that inspite of following examples and going through multiple iterations, the inference still takes N*4 seconds instead of N (running 4 processes) seconds. I am certain its because i dont fully understand whats going on here (in terms of multiple sessions creation) so please do shed some light on what i am missing ..code below

```
ocr_model      = None
decoderType = DecoderType.BestPath

def init_worker():
   global ocr_model
   ocr_graph = tf.Graph()
   decoderType = DecoderType.BestPath
   ocr_session = tf.Session(graph=ocr_graph)
   print('***********The graph launched in this session', ocr_session.graph, ocr_session.sess_str )
   ocr_model = OcrModel(open(FilePaths.fnCharList).read(), FilePaths.ocr_model_file, ocr_graph, \
                            ocr_session, decoderType, mustRestore=True)

def startParallel( inp_file_list ):
    import multiprocessing
    
    process_pool = multiprocessing.Pool( processes=4, initializer=init_worker )
    
    pool_output = process_pool.map( model_extract, inp_file_list )
    return pool_output

def model_extract(img_path):
    # .. whole bunch of image pre processing and then call the data loader
        loader = DataLoader(text_blocks, 20, ocr_model.imgSize, detect_text_res.oriented_orig_gray.copy())
        print("Total samples", len(loader.samples) )
        ## it works like a proper multi process till here
        start_time = time.time()
        while loader.hasNext():
            iterInfo = loader.getIteratorInfo()

            batch = loader.getNext()
            print( 'Batch:', iterInfo[0], '/', iterInfo[1], time.time() - start_time )
            (recognized, _) = ocr_model.inferBatch(batch=batch)
            ## this time is always number of process into 10 seconds while i would 
            ## expect all process to finish within 10 seconds NOT 10 * num process
            print( 'Time taken for recog ->', time.time() - start_time )
            # print(recognized)
            for id, text in zip(batch.ids, recognized):
                texts_obj[id] = text
    
### code for ocr model infer batch
    def inferBatch(self, batch, calcProbability=False, probabilityOfGT=False):
        "feed a batch into the NN to recognize the texts"

        # decode, optionally save RNN output
        numBatchElements = len(batch.imgs)
        evalRnnOutput = self.dump or calcProbability
        evalList = [self.decoder] +self.cnnKernels + ([self.ctcIn3dTBC] if evalRnnOutput else [])
        feedDict = {self.inputImgs: batch.imgs, self.seqLen: [OcrModel.maxTextLen] * numBatchElements,
                    self.is_train: False}
        print('ABOUT TO begin ->', batch)
        evalRes = self.sess.run(evalList, feedDict)
        decoded = evalRes[0]
        filters = evalRes[1]
        print('DONEBRO')
        # vis(filters)
        texts = self.decoderOutputToText(decoded, numBatchElements)
        # feed RNN output and recognized text into CTC loss to compute labeling probability
        probs = None
        if calcProbability:
            sparse = self.toSparse(batch.gtTexts) if probabilityOfGT else self.toSparse(texts)
            ctcInput = evalRes[2]
            evalList = self.lossPerElement
            feedDict = {self.savedCtcInput: ctcInput, self.gtTexts: sparse,
                        self.seqLen: [OcrModel.maxTextLen] * numBatchElements, self.is_train: False}
            lossVals = self.sess.run(evalList, feedDict)
            probs = np.exp(-lossVals)

        # dump the output of the NN to CSV file(s)
        if self.dump:
            self.dumpNNOutput(evalRes[2])

        return (texts, probs)
```

i am pretty sure this issue is due to my lack of understanding of how to use session run with multiple processes but i would assume that if i am creating 4 different session objects they should be able to run in their individual process and hence run parallely

Answer (score 0):

basically , the answer is you cant do any meaningful parallelization of TF code unless you have separate physical devices for each process.  So your session.run basically needs to have a cpu:x or a gpu:x associated with it ..else all parallel process's come and get stuck at the session.run call. TRY it .. we figured a simpler solution ..since the entire 16 gb memory with 1 physical cpu (T2 xlarge) was useless for above purpose, we actually split the task into 2 T2 large machines (since 8 gb of ram was plenty for 1 process + flask + gunicorn) ..we are using ALB along with auto scaling to ensure that at peak volume we can spawn 30-40 such instances, minimizing issues with multi processing and also keeping the costs waayyyy lower than paying for a bunch of GPUs (we would hve needed at least 2 ..do the math)

PS: if someone can prove to me that vCPUs can actually be used by TF, i will willingly transfer a gift certificate to your e-com account ..also i hope this isnt considered illegal by the mods ..sorry if it is